# Enviar emails diferente para mim e para o cliente apos preencher o formulário pelo phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tenho um formulário que envia os dados do cliente para um email, mas preciso que o cliente tambem receba uma copia deste email e com texto adicional, por exemplo:
Obrigado por se registrar, abaixo podera confirmar os dados enviados.

o codigo que estou utilizando:

```
if(isset($_POST['aderir_submit'])){
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
//Nova instância do PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Informa que será utilizado o SMTP para envio do e-mail
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Username =  "xxxxx@gmail.com";
$mail->Password =   "xxxx";

//Titulo do e-mail que será enviado
$mail->Subject  =   "Lutecia Club";

//Preenchimento do campo FROM do e-mail
$mail->From = "sales@luteciahotel.com";
$mail->FromName = "Lutecia Hotel";

 //Dados do formulario
$data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$first_name = $_POST['aderir_first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['aderir_last_name'];
$email = $_POST['aderir_email']; 
$pais = $_POST['aderir_pais']; 
$cidade = $_POST['aderir_cidade']; 
$telefone = $_POST['aderir_telefone']; 

//E-mail para a qual o e-mail será enviado
$mail->AddAddress("EMAIL-QUE-RECEBE-OS-DADOS@gmail.com");

//Conteúdo do e-mail
$mail->Body = "<h2>Adesão Lutecia Club</h2><br><h3>DADOS DO CLIENTE</h3><p style='background-color:#ccc;padding:10px;'><b>Nome:</b> " . $first_name . "<br> <b>Apelido: </b>" . $last_name . "<br> <b>Email:</b> " . $email . "<br><b>País: </b>" . $pais . "<br><b>Cidade:</b> " . $cidade . "<br> <b>Telefone: </b>" . $telefone . "<br><br></p>____________<br><br> LUTECIA CLUB<br><br>Data de envio: ". $data . ".";
$mail->AltBody = $mail->Body;

//Dispara o e-mail
$enviado = $mail->Send();


// Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
if ($enviado) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Formulário enviado. Entraremos em contatos o mais brevemente.");</script>';
} else {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Erro ao ligar-se ao servidor.");</script>';
}}
```

Pela função mail() tinha conseguido fazer, criando um nova funçao de envio

```
$envio = mail("para-mim@algum-email.com", "Assunto", "DADOS DO CLIENTE", $headers);
$envio2 = mail("para-ele@algum-email.com", "Assunto", "MENSAGEM DE OBRIGADO", $headers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O conceito é o mesmo. Tente fazer assim:

```
if(isset($_POST['aderir_submit'])){

    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
    //Nova instância do PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //Informa que será utilizado o SMTP para envio do e-mail
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Port       = 587;
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Username =  "xxxxx@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password =   "xxxx";

    //Titulo do e-mail que será enviado
    $mail->Subject  =   "Lutecia Club";

    //Preenchimento do campo FROM do e-mail
    $mail->From = "sales@luteciahotel.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Lutecia Hotel";

     //Dados do formulario
    $data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $first_name = $_POST['aderir_first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['aderir_last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['aderir_email']; 
    $pais = $_POST['aderir_pais']; 
    $cidade = $_POST['aderir_cidade']; 
    $telefone = $_POST['aderir_telefone']; 

    //E-mail para a qual o e-mail será enviado
    $mail->AddAddress("EMAIL-QUE-RECEBE-OS-DADOS@gmail.com");

    //Conteúdo do e-mail
    $mail->Body = "<h2>Adesão Lutecia Club</h2><br><h3>DADOS DO CLIENTE</h3><p style='background-color:#ccc;padding:10px;'><b>Nome:</b> " . $first_name . "<br> <b>Apelido: </b>" . $last_name . "<br> <b>Email:</b> " . $email . "<br><b>País: </b>" . $pais . "<br><b>Cidade:</b> " . $cidade . "<br> <b>Telefone: </b>" . $telefone . "<br><br></p>____________<br><br> LUTECIA CLUB<br><br>Data de envio: ". $data . ".";
    $mail->AltBody = $mail->Body;

    //Dispara o e-mail
    $enviadoSite = $mail->Send();


    /***************************************************************************/

    // clear addresses of all types
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients(); //Limpar todos os que destinatiarios: TO, CC, BCC

    //Titulo do e-mail que será enviado
    $mail->Subject  =   "OUTRO ASSUNTO";

    //E-mail para a qual o e-mail será enviado
    $mail->AddAddress("OUTRO-EMAIL@gmail.com");

    //Conteúdo do e-mail
    $mail->Body = "OUTRO TEXTO.";
    $mail->AltBody = $mail->Body;

    $enviadoCliente = $mail->Send();

    /***************************************************************************/

    // Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
    if ($enviadoSite && $enviadoCliente) {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Formulário enviado. Entraremos em contatos o mais brevemente.");</script>';
    } else {
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Erro ao ligar-se ao servidor.");</script>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Ola Thiago, o primeiro email foi enviado, mas o segundo não.

Comment: O endereço de e-mail do segundo envio está correto?

Comment: tiago, eu fiz assim: 
( $mail->AddAddress = $email; )
O objetivo é pegar o email da pessoa que preencheu o formulario

Comment: o correto era: $mail->AddAddress($email);

Answer (score 1):

Fiz teste no meu servidor e funcionou:
Só que ao invés de alerta usei janela flutuante.

```
// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php
require("class.phpmailer.php");

// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.meudominio.com"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usa autenticação SMTP
$mail->Username = 'seumail@dominio.com'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
$mail->Password = 'senha'; // Senha do servidor SMTP

// Define o remetente
$mail->From = "sales@luteciahotel.com";
$mail->FromName = "Lutecia Hotel";

//Dados do formulario
$data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$first_name = $_POST['aderir_first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['aderir_last_name'];
$email = $_POST['aderir_email']; 
$pais = $_POST['aderir_pais']; 
$cidade = $_POST['aderir_cidade']; 
$telefone = $_POST['aderir_telefone']; 

// Define os destinatário(s)
$mail->AddAddress("EMAIL-QUE-RECEBE-OS-DADOS@gmail.com");

//$mail->AddAddress('destinatario2@dominio.com', 'Nome do Destinatário');
//$mail->AddCC('destinatario3@dominio.com', 'Nome do Destinatário'); // Copia
//$mail->AddBCC('destinatario4@dominio.com', 'Nome do Destinatário'); // Cópia Oculta

// Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)

// Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
$mail->Subject  = "Mensagem Teste"; // Assunto da mensagem

$mensagem = "<h2>Adesão Lutecia Club</h2><br><h3>DADOS DO CLIENTE</h3><p style='background-color:#ccc;padding:10px;'><b>Nome:</b> " . $first_name . "<br> <b>Apelido: </b>" . $last_name . "<br> <b>Email:</b> " . $email . "<br><b>País: </b>" . $pais . "<br><b>Cidade:</b> " . $cidade . "<br> <b>Telefone: </b>" . $telefone . "<br><br></p>____________<br><br> LUTECIA CLUB<br><br>Data de envio: ". $data . ".";

$mail->Body = $mensagem;
$mail->AltBody = $mail->Body;

// Envia o e-mail
$enviado = $mail->Send();

// Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

$mail->Subject = "Outra Mensagem Teste"; // Assunto da mensagem

//E-mail do CLIENTE
$mail->AddAddress($email, $first_name." ".$last_name);

// Define a mensagem para o CLIENTE
$mail->Body = ' Obrigado por se registrar, abaixo poderá confirmar os dados enviados.<br>'.$mensagem;

$enviado2 = $mail->Send();

echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>'; 
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colorbox.css">';

echo ("
<style>#ajax{height:30px; width:450px;}</style>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
$.colorbox({inline:true, href:\".ajax\"});
});
}); 
</script>");


if ($enviado2) {
echo '<div style="display:none"><div id="ajax" class="ajax">Formulário enviado. Entraremos em contatos o mais brevemente.</div></div>');
} else {
echo '<div style="display:none"><div id="ajax" class="ajax">Erro ao ligar-se ao servidor.</div></div>');
}
```